# Let $H\lhd G$ and $\psi:G\to G/H,x\mapsto xH$ be a function. Show it is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism

Let $H\lhd G$ and $\psi:G \to G / H$, $x \mapsto xH$ be a function. I am struggling to show that the map is surjective.

Is it just so simple to say let $y:=xH \in G / H$ than it is trivial that we get $x \in G$ s.t. $\psi(x)=xH$ and hence it is surjective? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh true thanks, but is my argument right?

Comment: Every coset $gH \in G/H$ has always a preimage in $G$, which is $g$. Your map is a canonic projection on a normal subgroup, so it's surjective for sure and it is really easy to see.

Comment: $G/H$ is defined as the set of elements of the form $xH$, where $x\in G$. This guarantees surjectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your argument is correct.

A very minor gripe: you don't "get" $x$ such that $\psi(x)=xH$. You actually start with one, and as you say, it trivially satisfies $\psi(x)=xH$.

Answer (score 4):

Take any element $y \in G/H$. By *definition* of $G/H$, there exists $x \in G$ such that $y=xH$. Then by definition of $\psi$, this can be rewritten as $y=\psi(x)$. So every element of $G/H$ is in the image of $\psi$, i.e. $\psi$ is surjective.